# Paste within visible area in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copy-and-paste

Photoshop CC images are pasted in the middle of the document which require me to zoom back or drag layer from very far (webdesign may be really tall).

In Photoshop CS images were pasted somewhere in a currently viewed part of the document. Is there a way to make Photoshop CC behave like this?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found that you can make a selection with the related tool (dashed line) then paste to make image appear wherever you want.

Edit : Looking back to this it's related to Artboard feature. With multiples artboards it will be pasted in the middle of active artboard otherwise in the middle of the viewed working space.

Comment: You already figured out a way to do what you wanted, but just in case you have a use for it, I thought I might as well share a script I made for myself to place images inside selections. Though be aware that It has been only in my personal use so there may be scenarios that I've not considered yet and will cause it to fail. [Link to the script](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/e1b67f3762e60200601b6c18dbe4223e)

Comment: Decided to write a new comment, because my previous one was easy to misunderstand as me offering a script that does exactly the same thing as this `selection → paste` that OP found out about. — So, to clarify, the script places an image inside a selection and resizes it to fit or fill the selection. [**Example gifs**](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/e1b67f3762e60200601b6c18dbe4223e#gistcomment-2678485)

Comment: Didn't try your solution as it is a quite old topic and I'm not in Photoshop theses days. I don't know if it does exactly what I ve asked for (the point is positioning not resizing) but it may  still help others. Regards.