# Is it possible to maintain position when pasting into a layer mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

The question says it all I think.

When I paste into a layer mask, the pasted pixels re-orientate themselves into the centre of the image.

But I would like them to maintain the exact position they were in on the layer I copied them from.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Related - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108047/how-to-paste-a-copied-selection-in-the-same-spot-as-the-original-selection?rq=1

Comment: Ta, perfect. I did search, but that didn't come up for my terms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paste a copied selection in the same spot as the original selection?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108047/how-to-paste-a-copied-selection-in-the-same-spot-as-the-original-selection)

Comment: This is not directly related to the question, but since I see similar stuff here I thought I might as well post this here: [https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/103882/2332 **check my comments below the answer**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/103882/2332)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Use Paste-in-Place, Layer via Copy or Alt Drag

Use:

**Copy in Place:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Or

**Layer via Copy** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

*Both do the same thing with layers.

### Copy Mask

Also, when copying one layer mask on to a new layer. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag to the new layer.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your welcome. My pleasure :)

Comment: maybe you want to fix your title to pâte or coller en place

Comment: That made me laugh so much. Maybe I should move it to the food community? Haha! Thanks for cheering me up :)